# Parameter is not valid. - only happens with Gifs

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have some code that will allow a user to upload an image to my server.

its worked fine for months accepting just PNG and JPEG's, as initially it was used for photographs.

now I want uses to upload banners, so I need to accept gifs, but every time I try and upload a gif I get this error.

```
"Parameter is not valid."
```

on this bit of code

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_SavePath + imageFileName));
```

the weird thing is it works fine with PNG's and JPEG's bit not at all with GIF's

I've been googling for a few hours now and from what i get, it seems that this error is a pain and doesn't describe the real issue.

can anyone help ?

Thanks

Truegilly

Comment: can you upload your Gifs here on SO or upload somewhere else and give us the link? Are they animated Gifs?

Comment: It is GDI+'s version of the FileNotFound exception.  And some other ones, like the image being too large to fit in memory.

Comment: when i upload a gif, if i debug before the line above, it saves the image, but its in a bad format, ie i cannot view it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method is throwing? Bitmap's constructor or MapPath?

**If Bitmap:**

Are you sure the GIF is valid?  Other programs might be able to read it even if it's not 100% to spec, but perhaps Bitmap is being more picky.

Have you tried many different GIF files and had this problem?

**If MapPath:**

Is the name of the GIF not valid once it gets passed to MapPath?  Check to see what it is.

If the GIF is possibly not a good one -- you can try my company's product, [DotImage Photo](http://atalasoft.com/photofree), which is free.  It's got a class called `AtalaImage` that you can use like Bitmap and it can read images that might be off-spec.